# Efeito de fade no texto ao rolar a página

Tags: html5, css3

Gostaria de aplicar um efeito ao rolar o texto de uma div, semelhante ao efeito abaixo (que roubei de um site):

PS: Executar como fullscreen;

```css
body {
  background: #f8fafc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Crimson Text", serif;
  color: 444;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1, h3, h4, p {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}

h4 {
  color: #666;
}

div.blur {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

div.blur.bottom {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.blur div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

div.blur div.itm_1 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.99);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.98px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.98px);
}

div.blur div.itm_2 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.98);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.96px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.96px);
}

div.blur div.itm_3 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.97);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.94px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.94px);
}

div.blur div.itm_4 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.96);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.92px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.92px);
}

div.blur div.itm_5 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.95);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.9px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.9px);
}

div.blur div.itm_6 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.94);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.88px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.88px);
}

div.blur div.itm_7 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.93);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.86px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.86px);
}

div.blur div.itm_8 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.92);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.84px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.84px);
}

div.blur div.itm_9 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.91);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.82px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.82px);
}

div.blur div.itm_10 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.9);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.8px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.8px);
}

div.blur div.itm_11 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.89);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.78px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.78px);
}

div.blur div.itm_12 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.88);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.76px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.76px);
}

div.blur div.itm_13 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.87);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.74px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.74px);
}

div.blur div.itm_14 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.86);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.72px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.72px);
}

div.blur div.itm_15 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.85);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.7px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.7px);
}

div.blur div.itm_16 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.84);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.68px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.68px);
}

div.blur div.itm_17 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.83);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.66px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.66px);
}

div.blur div.itm_18 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.82);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.64px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.64px);
}

div.blur div.itm_19 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.81);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.62px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.62px);
}

div.blur div.itm_20 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.8);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.6px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.6px);
}

div.blur div.itm_21 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.79);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.58px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.58px);
}

div.blur div.itm_22 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.78);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.56px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.56px);
}

div.blur div.itm_23 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.77);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.54px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.54px);
}

div.blur div.itm_24 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.76);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.52px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.52px);
}

div.blur div.itm_25 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.75);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.5px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.5px);
}

div.blur div.itm_26 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.74);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.48px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.48px);
}

div.blur div.itm_27 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.73);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.46px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.46px);
}

div.blur div.itm_28 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.72);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.44px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.44px);
}

div.blur div.itm_29 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.71);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.42px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.42px);
}

div.blur div.itm_30 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.7);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.4px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.4px);
}

div.blur div.itm_31 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.69);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.38px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.38px);
}

div.blur div.itm_32 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.68);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.36px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.36px);
}

div.blur div.itm_33 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.67);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.34px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.34px);
}

div.blur div.itm_34 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.66);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.32px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.32px);
}

div.blur div.itm_35 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.65);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.3px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.3px);
}

div.blur div.itm_36 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.64);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.28px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.28px);
}

div.blur div.itm_37 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.63);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.26px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.26px);
}

div.blur div.itm_38 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.62);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.24px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.24px);
}

div.blur div.itm_39 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.61);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.22px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.22px);
}

div.blur div.itm_40 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.6);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.2px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.2px);
}

div.blur div.itm_41 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.59);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.18px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.18px);
}

div.blur div.itm_42 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.58);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.16px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.16px);
}

div.blur div.itm_43 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.57);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.14px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.14px);
}

div.blur div.itm_44 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.56);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.12px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.12px);
}

div.blur div.itm_45 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.55);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.1px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.1px);
}

div.blur div.itm_46 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.54);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.08px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.08px);
}

div.blur div.itm_47 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.53);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.06px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.06px);
}

div.blur div.itm_48 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.52);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.04px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.04px);
}

div.blur div.itm_49 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.51);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.02px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1.02px);
}

div.blur div.itm_50 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.5);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}

div.blur div.itm_51 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.49);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.98px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.98px);
}

div.blur div.itm_52 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.48);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.96px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.96px);
}

div.blur div.itm_53 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.47);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.94px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.94px);
}

div.blur div.itm_54 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.46);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.92px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.92px);
}

div.blur div.itm_55 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.45);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.9px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.9px);
}

div.blur div.itm_56 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.44);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.88px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.88px);
}

div.blur div.itm_57 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.43);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.86px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.86px);
}

div.blur div.itm_58 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.42);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.84px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.84px);
}

div.blur div.itm_59 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.41);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.82px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.82px);
}

div.blur div.itm_60 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.4);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.8px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.8px);
}

div.blur div.itm_61 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.39);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.78px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.78px);
}

div.blur div.itm_62 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.38);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.76px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.76px);
}

div.blur div.itm_63 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.37);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.74px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.74px);
}

div.blur div.itm_64 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.36);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.72px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.72px);
}

div.blur div.itm_65 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.35);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.7px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.7px);
}

div.blur div.itm_66 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.34);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.68px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.68px);
}

div.blur div.itm_67 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.33);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.66px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.66px);
}

div.blur div.itm_68 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.32);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.64px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.64px);
}

div.blur div.itm_69 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.31);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.62px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.62px);
}

div.blur div.itm_70 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.3);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.6px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.6px);
}

div.blur div.itm_71 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.29);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.58px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.58px);
}

div.blur div.itm_72 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.28);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.56px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.56px);
}

div.blur div.itm_73 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.27);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.54px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.54px);
}

div.blur div.itm_74 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.26);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.52px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.52px);
}

div.blur div.itm_75 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.25);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.5px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.5px);
}

div.blur div.itm_76 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.24);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.48px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.48px);
}

div.blur div.itm_77 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.23);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.46px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.46px);
}

div.blur div.itm_78 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.22);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.44px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.44px);
}

div.blur div.itm_79 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.21);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.42px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.42px);
}

div.blur div.itm_80 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.4px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.4px);
}

div.blur div.itm_81 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.19);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.38px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.38px);
}

div.blur div.itm_82 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.18);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.36px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.36px);
}

div.blur div.itm_83 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.17);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.34px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.34px);
}

div.blur div.itm_84 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.16);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.32px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.32px);
}

div.blur div.itm_85 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.15);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.3px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.3px);
}

div.blur div.itm_86 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.14);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.28px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.28px);
}

div.blur div.itm_87 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.13);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.26px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.26px);
}

div.blur div.itm_88 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.12);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.24px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.24px);
}

div.blur div.itm_89 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.11);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.22px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.22px);
}

div.blur div.itm_90 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.1);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.2px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.2px);
}

div.blur div.itm_91 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.09);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.18px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.18px);
}

div.blur div.itm_92 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.08);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.16px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.16px);
}

div.blur div.itm_93 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.07);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.14px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.14px);
}

div.blur div.itm_94 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.06);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.12px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.12px);
}

div.blur div.itm_95 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.05);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.1px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.1px);
}

div.blur div.itm_96 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.04);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.08px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.08px);
}

div.blur div.itm_97 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.03);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.06px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.06px);
}

div.blur div.itm_98 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.02);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.04px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.04px);
}

div.blur div.itm_99 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0.01);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.02px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0.02px);
}

div.blur div.itm_100 {
  background: rgba(248, 250, 252, 0);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur top">
  <div class="itm_1"></div>
  <div class="itm_2"></div>
  <div class="itm_3"></div>
  <div class="itm_4"></div>
  <div class="itm_5"></div>
  <div class="itm_6"></div>
  <div class="itm_7"></div>
  <div class="itm_8"></div>
  <div class="itm_9"></div>
  <div class="itm_10"></div>
  <div class="itm_11"></div>
  <div class="itm_12"></div>
  <div class="itm_13"></div>
  <div class="itm_14"></div>
  <div class="itm_15"></div>
  <div class="itm_16"></div>
  <div class="itm_17"></div>
  <div class="itm_18"></div>
  <div class="itm_19"></div>
  <div class="itm_20"></div>
  <div class="itm_21"></div>
  <div class="itm_22"></div>
  <div class="itm_23"></div>
  <div class="itm_24"></div>
  <div class="itm_25"></div>
  <div class="itm_26"></div>
  <div class="itm_27"></div>
  <div class="itm_28"></div>
  <div class="itm_29"></div>
  <div class="itm_30"></div>
  <div class="itm_31"></div>
  <div class="itm_32"></div>
  <div class="itm_33"></div>
  <div class="itm_34"></div>
  <div class="itm_35"></div>
  <div class="itm_36"></div>
  <div class="itm_37"></div>
  <div class="itm_38"></div>
  <div class="itm_39"></div>
  <div class="itm_40"></div>
  <div class="itm_41"></div>
  <div class="itm_42"></div>
  <div class="itm_43"></div>
  <div class="itm_44"></div>
  <div class="itm_45"></div>
  <div class="itm_46"></div>
  <div class="itm_47"></div>
  <div class="itm_48"></div>
  <div class="itm_49"></div>
  <div class="itm_50"></div>
  <div class="itm_51"></div>
  <div class="itm_52"></div>
  <div class="itm_53"></div>
  <div class="itm_54"></div>
  <div class="itm_55"></div>
  <div class="itm_56"></div>
  <div class="itm_57"></div>
  <div class="itm_58"></div>
  <div class="itm_59"></div>
  <div class="itm_60"></div>
  <div class="itm_61"></div>
  <div class="itm_62"></div>
  <div class="itm_63"></div>
  <div class="itm_64"></div>
  <div class="itm_65"></div>
  <div class="itm_66"></div>
  <div class="itm_67"></div>
  <div class="itm_68"></div>
  <div class="itm_69"></div>
  <div class="itm_70"></div>
  <div class="itm_71"></div>
  <div class="itm_72"></div>
  <div class="itm_73"></div>
  <div class="itm_74"></div>
  <div class="itm_75"></div>
  <div class="itm_76"></div>
  <div class="itm_77"></div>
  <div class="itm_78"></div>
  <div class="itm_79"></div>
  <div class="itm_80"></div>
  <div class="itm_81"></div>
  <div class="itm_82"></div>
  <div class="itm_83"></div>
  <div class="itm_84"></div>
  <div class="itm_85"></div>
  <div class="itm_86"></div>
  <div class="itm_87"></div>
  <div class="itm_88"></div>
  <div class="itm_89"></div>
  <div class="itm_90"></div>
  <div class="itm_91"></div>
  <div class="itm_92"></div>
  <div class="itm_93"></div>
  <div class="itm_94"></div>
  <div class="itm_95"></div>
  <div class="itm_96"></div>
  <div class="itm_97"></div>
  <div class="itm_98"></div>
  <div class="itm_99"></div>
  <div class="itm_100"></div>
</div>
<h1>Text fading away</h1>
<h4>Only (sort of) works on safari...</h4>
<h3>I just had this idea of text being blurred away once you start scrolling. Turns out the rendering becomes quite glitchy after adding so much blur elements on a single page.</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent facilisis, est id faucibus ornare, nunc orci tristique magna, quis cursus orci urna bibendum mauris. Etiam varius augue odio. Vestibulum a nunc vitae elit tincidunt efficitur. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed convallis maximus nisl nec laoreet. Phasellus risus quam, accumsan non ligula ac, vulputate sollicitudin massa. Duis vitae nulla ligula. Suspendisse maximus eros ac mauris molestie, non congue quam vestibulum. Sed eget dui aliquet, ullamcorper libero quis, vestibulum mauris. Pellentesque sit amet velit sit amet lorem sodales lobortis. Curabitur quis fermentum velit, vitae dignissim risus. Nam convallis sodales ligula, euismod gravida ipsum consectetur in. Nam ultrices, mauris vitae vehicula molestie, tortor nisl tempus urna, nec pulvinar nunc lorem eget velit. In interdum felis sit amet velit tempor hendrerit. Morbi quis odio id erat finibus hendrerit.</p>
<p>Aenean feugiat venenatis mi, sit amet consectetur nibh eleifend tincidunt. Nullam et libero lectus. Donec eget neque iaculis, tempus nisi id, pellentesque ipsum. Curabitur nec ipsum eleifend, placerat turpis aliquam, ullamcorper quam. Donec et elementum tellus. Suspendisse fermentum mi quis erat aliquet consequat. Nam sit amet libero eget orci facilisis pretium eu a felis. Maecenas facilisis felis turpis, ac pharetra ante consequat dignissim.</p>
<p>Cras sit amet mauris vel sapien sodales faucibus non non est. Fusce aliquam nibh quis turpis tempor auctor. Phasellus facilisis urna eu nibh venenatis porttitor. Nulla faucibus facilisis faucibus. Proin in massa cursus justo dictum faucibus sit amet suscipit ante. Quisque iaculis nibh ac nibh vestibulum venenatis. Proin quis leo imperdiet, facilisis ipsum et, pellentesque nulla. Curabitur ultricies sagittis suscipit. Curabitur pulvinar elementum neque nec lobortis. Nam nibh dolor, sollicitudin non ex eget, imperdiet pellentesque sapien. Fusce a mauris ullamcorper, dignissim sapien et, lobortis arcu.</p>
<p>Donec posuere ipsum sit amet purus elementum ullamcorper. Donec sed maximus mi, vitae elementum mi. Etiam blandit, ex sed pulvinar finibus, mi lorem commodo mi, non tincidunt quam sem ut urna. Integer at sem purus. Aenean tempus, mi at tempor feugiat, nisi elit elementum turpis, vitae iaculis dui neque in diam. Curabitur elementum tellus nec dolor volutpat vestibulum. Sed ligula ipsum, faucibus et mi sit amet, gravida commodo lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum sed sagittis est. Praesent lorem nunc, egestas non convallis sed, accumsan sed lacus. Nam diam augue, mollis quis tristique eu, sagittis nec magna. Donec id massa eu risus faucibus tristique nec id purus. Proin turpis odio, consequat eget feugiat non, mollis at velit.</p>
<p>Nullam vitae justo aliquet, viverra mi ut, fermentum elit. Proin efficitur tempor euismod. Nulla pellentesque pharetra quam. Suspendisse a elit lacinia, porttitor enim id, auctor risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec cursus nunc pharetra luctus blandit. Curabitur et tincidunt urna. Proin a purus a nunc egestas commodo vitae ut est. Proin vel vehicula ipsum, non semper est. Mauris feugiat nunc leo. Nunc gravida, mauris sed posuere tempus, orci enim porttitor erat, sodales venenatis lorem tortor eget massa. Nunc suscipit, purus sed tincidunt tempus, est nunc dictum lacus, a consectetur neque velit imperdiet magna. Duis sodales iaculis enim, mattis commodo ex condimentum vel.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="blur bottom">
  <div class="itm_100"></div>
  <div class="itm_99"></div>
  <div class="itm_98"></div>
  <div class="itm_97"></div>
  <div class="itm_96"></div>
  <div class="itm_95"></div>
  <div class="itm_94"></div>
  <div class="itm_93"></div>
  <div class="itm_92"></div>
  <div class="itm_91"></div>
  <div class="itm_90"></div>
  <div class="itm_89"></div>
  <div class="itm_88"></div>
  <div class="itm_87"></div>
  <div class="itm_86"></div>
  <div class="itm_85"></div>
  <div class="itm_84"></div>
  <div class="itm_83"></div>
  <div class="itm_82"></div>
  <div class="itm_81"></div>
  <div class="itm_80"></div>
  <div class="itm_79"></div>
  <div class="itm_78"></div>
  <div class="itm_77"></div>
  <div class="itm_76"></div>
  <div class="itm_75"></div>
  <div class="itm_74"></div>
  <div class="itm_73"></div>
  <div class="itm_72"></div>
  <div class="itm_71"></div>
  <div class="itm_70"></div>
  <div class="itm_69"></div>
  <div class="itm_68"></div>
  <div class="itm_67"></div>
  <div class="itm_66"></div>
  <div class="itm_65"></div>
  <div class="itm_64"></div>
  <div class="itm_63"></div>
  <div class="itm_62"></div>
  <div class="itm_61"></div>
  <div class="itm_60"></div>
  <div class="itm_59"></div>
  <div class="itm_58"></div>
  <div class="itm_57"></div>
  <div class="itm_56"></div>
  <div class="itm_55"></div>
  <div class="itm_54"></div>
  <div class="itm_53"></div>
  <div class="itm_52"></div>
  <div class="itm_51"></div>
  <div class="itm_50"></div>
  <div class="itm_49"></div>
  <div class="itm_48"></div>
  <div class="itm_47"></div>
  <div class="itm_46"></div>
  <div class="itm_45"></div>
  <div class="itm_44"></div>
  <div class="itm_43"></div>
  <div class="itm_42"></div>
  <div class="itm_41"></div>
  <div class="itm_40"></div>
  <div class="itm_39"></div>
  <div class="itm_38"></div>
  <div class="itm_37"></div>
  <div class="itm_36"></div>
  <div class="itm_35"></div>
  <div class="itm_34"></div>
  <div class="itm_33"></div>
  <div class="itm_32"></div>
  <div class="itm_31"></div>
  <div class="itm_30"></div>
  <div class="itm_29"></div>
  <div class="itm_28"></div>
  <div class="itm_27"></div>
  <div class="itm_26"></div>
  <div class="itm_25"></div>
  <div class="itm_24"></div>
  <div class="itm_23"></div>
  <div class="itm_22"></div>
  <div class="itm_21"></div>
  <div class="itm_20"></div>
  <div class="itm_19"></div>
  <div class="itm_18"></div>
  <div class="itm_17"></div>
  <div class="itm_16"></div>
  <div class="itm_15"></div>
  <div class="itm_14"></div>
  <div class="itm_13"></div>
  <div class="itm_12"></div>
  <div class="itm_11"></div>
  <div class="itm_10"></div>
  <div class="itm_9"></div>
  <div class="itm_8"></div>
  <div class="itm_7"></div>
  <div class="itm_6"></div>
  <div class="itm_5"></div>
  <div class="itm_4"></div>
  <div class="itm_3"></div>
  <div class="itm_2"></div>
  <div class="itm_1"></div>
</div>
```

Como poderia criar esse efeito sem criar toda essa gambiarra de forma que funcione em todos os browsers atuais?

Comment: Utilize *background gradient* ou uma imagem *png* (para navegadores mais antigos) com o efeito.

Comment: como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Cara cheguei a um resultado similar, veja se é algo parecido com isso!

```css
body {
  background: #f8fafc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Crimson Text", serif;
  color: 444;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1, h3, h4, p {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}

h4 {
  color: #666;
}

#fade {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255, 0.9), rgba(255,255,255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.9));
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text fading away</h1>

<h4>Only (sort of) works on safari...</h4>

<h3>I just had this idea of text being blurred away once you start scrolling. Turns out the rendering becomes quite glitchy after adding so much blur elements on a single page.</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent facilisis, est id faucibus ornare, nunc orci tristique magna, quis cursus orci urna bibendum mauris. Etiam varius augue odio. Vestibulum a nunc vitae elit tincidunt efficitur. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed convallis maximus nisl nec laoreet. Phasellus risus quam, accumsan non ligula ac, vulputate sollicitudin massa. Duis vitae nulla ligula. Suspendisse maximus eros ac mauris molestie, non congue quam vestibulum. Sed eget dui aliquet, ullamcorper libero quis, vestibulum mauris. Pellentesque sit amet velit sit amet lorem sodales lobortis. Curabitur quis fermentum velit, vitae dignissim risus. Nam convallis sodales ligula, euismod gravida ipsum consectetur in. Nam ultrices, mauris vitae vehicula molestie, tortor nisl tempus urna, nec pulvinar nunc lorem eget velit. In interdum felis sit amet velit tempor hendrerit. Morbi quis odio id erat finibus hendrerit.</p>
<p>Aenean feugiat venenatis mi, sit amet consectetur nibh eleifend tincidunt. Nullam et libero lectus. Donec eget neque iaculis, tempus nisi id, pellentesque ipsum. Curabitur nec ipsum eleifend, placerat turpis aliquam, ullamcorper quam. Donec et elementum tellus. Suspendisse fermentum mi quis erat aliquet consequat. Nam sit amet libero eget orci facilisis pretium eu a felis. Maecenas facilisis felis turpis, ac pharetra ante consequat dignissim.</p>
<p>Cras sit amet mauris vel sapien sodales faucibus non non est. Fusce aliquam nibh quis turpis tempor auctor. Phasellus facilisis urna eu nibh venenatis porttitor. Nulla faucibus facilisis faucibus. Proin in massa cursus justo dictum faucibus sit amet suscipit ante. Quisque iaculis nibh ac nibh vestibulum venenatis. Proin quis leo imperdiet, facilisis ipsum et, pellentesque nulla. Curabitur ultricies sagittis suscipit. Curabitur pulvinar elementum neque nec lobortis. Nam nibh dolor, sollicitudin non ex eget, imperdiet pellentesque sapien. Fusce a mauris ullamcorper, dignissim sapien et, lobortis arcu.</p>
<p>Donec posuere ipsum sit amet purus elementum ullamcorper. Donec sed maximus mi, vitae elementum mi. Etiam blandit, ex sed pulvinar finibus, mi lorem commodo mi, non tincidunt quam sem ut urna. Integer at sem purus. Aenean tempus, mi at tempor feugiat, nisi elit elementum turpis, vitae iaculis dui neque in diam. Curabitur elementum tellus nec dolor volutpat vestibulum. Sed ligula ipsum, faucibus et mi sit amet, gravida commodo lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum sed sagittis est. Praesent lorem nunc, egestas non convallis sed, accumsan sed lacus. Nam diam augue, mollis quis tristique eu, sagittis nec magna. Donec id massa eu risus faucibus tristique nec id purus. Proin turpis odio, consequat eget feugiat non, mollis at velit.</p>
<p>Nullam vitae justo aliquet, viverra mi ut, fermentum elit. Proin efficitur tempor euismod. Nulla pellentesque pharetra quam. Suspendisse a elit lacinia, porttitor enim id, auctor risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec cursus nunc pharetra luctus blandit. Curabitur et tincidunt urna. Proin a purus a nunc egestas commodo vitae ut est. Proin vel vehicula ipsum, non semper est. Mauris feugiat nunc leo. Nunc gravida, mauris sed posuere tempus, orci enim porttitor erat, sodales venenatis lorem tortor eget massa. Nunc suscipit, purus sed tincidunt tempus, est nunc dictum lacus, a consectetur neque velit imperdiet magna. Duis sodales iaculis enim, mattis commodo ex condimentum vel.</p>
<div id="fade"></div>
```

Comment: Como comentei na resposta do @hugocsl esse efeito não vai funcionar caso o background tenha uma imagem de fundo.

Comment: Onde você iria adicionar esta imagem de fundo ?

Comment: no background da pagina

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi qual sua intenção, seria que o background da pagina não tivesse o fade ?

Comment: Altere a segunda linha do seu CSS de `background: #f8fafc;` para `background: blue;` e veja o resultado